# Select Except Select with extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's suppose I have a sql query:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Persons1
EXCEPT
SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Persons2
```

It will work if the tables have the same structure. But now I also want to have an extra column in my table - Id of person  present in first table but absent in second table

```
SELECT PersonId,FirstName,LastName FROM Persons1
EXCEPT
SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Persons2
```

won't work of course.

What would be the best way to get it? My real life case has much more columns and some values may be null.

Comment: what would be an example of the desired data set?

Comment: Which dbms??????

Comment: I thought it's a general Sql problem but I'm using Sql Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT 
    p1.PersonId, p1.FirstName, p1.LastName
FROM Persons1 p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Persons2 p2
    WHERE
        p2.FirstName = p1.FirstName
        AND p2.LastName = p2.LastName
);
```

This will give you rows from `Persons1` whose `FirstName` and `LastName` do not exist on `Persons2`.

Comment: I'm afraid p2.FirstName = p1.FirstName won't return a row if the value is null

Comment: @RRM Have you even tried to run it???  I don't see anything wrong with the query.

Comment: @RRM, just modify the conditions to your liking. I'm just suggesting using `NOT EXISTS` as an alternative.

Comment: Ok, I guess there isn't any trick without writing list of WHEREs So I accept this answer as correct as it was the first.

Comment: additional examples could help be more direct in avoiding those "list of WHEREs"

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT P.PersonID
    ,E.FirstName
    ,E.LastName
FROM (
    SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Persons1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Persons2
) E
INNER JOIN Person1 P
    ON P.FirstName = E.FirstName
    AND P.LastName = E.LastName
```

Comment: The same problem with nulls as above. You can of course add logic like ISNULL(Name.'') or ISNULL(Age,0) but it makes code less clear. And if I have 15 columns in my SELECT I have to write 15 comparisons. I wonder if it can be done in a better way.

Comment: May I request that you give a more complete scenario as to exactly what you are wanting/working with.

This might also provide a easier way as there could be union statements or CTE logic that could do what your wanting, but my answer was directed at the question as given, unless I missed something.

My apologies.